# Is it necessary to Authenticate with OAuth 2 for Simply play Youtube video In Android App?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

First, I apologize my english is not good.

I want to Play Youtube Video in Android, use [Youtube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

So, I Created API Key for Youtube Data API v3 in developer dashboard, and it works!

But, dashboard warned against oauth2.

My Question is, Is it necessary to authenticate with OAuth2 for android app, only play youtube video?

I'm not interested in user information. I want play video only.

And, Play video, does it affect API limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to authenticate with OAuth2 to just play youtube video. If you are giving like or subscribe functionality in your youtube player then you should implement oAuth2. Because it need particular user's information. But in your case there is **no need to authenticate with OAuth2**.

Comment: Welcome amagasa!